# Basic approach for NSManagedObjects in an application without a UI

Tags: core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I'm writing a client/server Cocoa application.  The application server doesn't have a UI.  To simplify this question, consider the data to be moving via CFNetwork streams (not a web app). Each iOS client has the ability to request tasks to be performed the OSX application server, such as:

- Fetch and return a record or set of records
- Create a record
- Update a record

I see UI examples where the NSManagedObjectContext data is managed by a NSObjectController/NSArrayController and a binding to a View.

I won't have a View on the server, and I understand that I shouldn't move this functionality into the AppDelegate.

What approach should I use?  For example, should I create classes that each respond to a set of related client requests where each class owns a NSManagedObjectContext related to its unit of work?  Forgive my pseudocode:

```
@interface AccountManagement : NSObject
NSManagedObjectContext *contextAccounts;
-(void)fetchAccounts;
-(void)createAccount;
-(void)updateAccount;
@end

@interface SiteManagement : NSObject
NSManagedObjectContext *contextAccounts;
-(void)fetchSite;
-(void)createSite;
-(void)updateSite;
@end
```

I'm also struggling to see how an NSArrayController fits into this structure, perhaps I don't need one since there is no UI?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are exactly on target with your `NSObject` derived classes. You do exactly the same as in the examples, just leaving out the UI parts.

BTW, your two class prototypes seem a bit redundant (just a different entity). I am sure they could be combined into one.